# lightSlider is not a function, wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add lightslider(http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/index.html) in WordPress but I got error

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).lightSlider is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):99m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2m.extend.ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2J @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.2:2
```

I'm trying with the simplest example from their website

HTML

```
<ul id="lightSlider">
  <li>
      <h3>First Slide</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h3>Second Slide</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum Excepteur amet adipisicing fugiat velit nisi.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h3>Third Slide</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum Excepteur amet adipisicing fugiat velit nisi.</p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Also tried to add noConflict() function
//jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#lightSlider").lightSlider(); 

});
</script>
```

Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like if you were not loading the plugin before using it

Comment: Have you included the libraries in your html, as well?

Comment: Yes, I checked all files in Resources folder, It loads .js and .css file for plugin. About loading, I'm using wp_enqueue_script() WordPress function, load jQuery first and then lightslider.js. Have you any idea how can I do that on other way, to be sure that I load it before using?

Comment: So in your rendered html you can see the line which loads the script? The error you are getting is because the script was not been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved problem. The problem exist because somehow jQuery were loaded after lightSlider.js . I don't know how this happened, I just put jQuery to load first in wp_enqueue_script(), before anything else (before css, too) and lightslider.js at the end.

I hope this answer will help someone more. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I have fixed it. 
Just copy the entire code of lightslider.js and past it into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //code of lightslider 

});
```

Comment: No, I mean the code of lightslider.js need to be within a $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: @CristianPunkRock has a point. Instead of calling the library, if you copy.paste the entire lightSlider.js code and put that javascript within the onready block, it works. I upvoted because of that.

Answer (score 1):

You should put dependency `array('jquery')` to load jQuery first.

Example:

```
  wp_register_script( 'lightslider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/lightSlider/js/lightslider.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the deferred load

```
<script src="js/lightslider.js defer"></script>
```